In (condensed matter) QFT, are creation and annihilation operators completely defined by commutation relation and their action on vacuum?
Consider an atomic chain of $N$ atoms in PBC. At the first sight the Hilbert space is defined by tensor product of the $N$ atom Hilbert spaces. However, when we rewrite the Hamiltonian in terms of a sum of phonon Hamiltonians, it's more natural to talk about phonon number representation. But this time, we can't explicitly write out what is, say, a two phonon state, at least not in terms of a tensor product of atom wavefunctions. So I guess the two-phonon state can only be defined by the creation operator, which I'm cool with.
Now my problem becomes that, in this case, it seems I can't induce the behavior of a creation operator $a_k^\dagger$ on one particle state from its behavior on vacuum, which I could do with the explicit definition of the number representation.
For example, if we start with number representation and use it to define creation operator
$$a_k^\dagger a_{k'}^\dagger\vert\Omega\rangle=\vert kk'\rangle$$
up to symmetrization. All we need to know is $a_k^\dagger\vert\Omega\rangle=\vert k\rangle$, the action on the multi-particle state is just tensor product a $\vert k'\rangle$ and then symmetrization.
But with the atomic chain case, there is no easy procedure.

In condensed matter you usually start from the one-particle Hilbert space, and then construct the Fock space and the creation and annihilation operators. In terms of $C^*$ algebras, I think this is the Fock-Cook representation.

But I don't fully get your question. Could you rephrase it? Include equations?

I see! If we start from one-particle Hilbert space, it's enough to define the action on ground state. But in general it's not enough to use commutation relation and the action on vacuum to define creation and annihilation operators(?), which is what happens in the atomic chain example, we really do need every bit of information in the definition of creation operator using X_i and P_i.

I've added more clarification. Is it clear now?

In Cond Mat QFT, the relevant states are the many-particle electron ground state, which is extremely far from the vacuum state of HEP QFT. For the phonons, the equivalent of the photon's blackbody radiation state should be the relevant state. I dont know why you are attempting anything from vacuum state.

If I understood you correctly, consider/think about/double check this: Assume the $N$ atoms are distinguishable; the Hamiltonian can be written in the form $H=\sum_{k=1}^N \omega_k a_k^* a_k$ and acts on $\mathfrak h^{\otimes N}$, where $\mathfrak h$ is the infinite-dim. Hilbert space of one atom. Then construct a $N$-dimensional Hilbert space with some orthonormal basis $|e_k\rangle$ and Hamiltonian $h=\sum_k \omega_k |e_k\rangle\langle  e_k|$. From this $N$-dimensional space, construct the Fock space $ F$, where the Hamiltonian takes the form $\tilde H=\sum\limits_k \omega_k b_k^*b_k$.

Now if the representation of the $a_k$ on $\mathfrak h^{\otimes N}$ is irreducible, the Stone-von Neumann theoren should apply and guarantee the existence of a unitary $U:F\to \mathfrak h^{\otimes N}$ such that $Ub_kU^=a_k$ and thus $U\tilde HU^=H$. Then the ground state of $H$ is just $U|0\rangle$, where $|0\rangle \in F$ is the vacuum state. From this, it also follows that e.g. $a_k U|0\rangle=0$ etc. I don't know if there is a canonical choice of this $N$-dimensional space/ the $U$ map, though.

@TobiasFünke I saw the comment you tagged meow and the post you deleted. I don't know why you are unsure of yourself but one can either treat the mass points classically as a field and then quantise that, or upgrade your normal modes harmonic oscillator ladder operators, and both ways lead to the same and good QFT, and then what I said applies. These are the standard and good inputs into Migdal-Eliashberg theory.

@naturallyInconsistent I am sorry. I am not sure if I understood the question correctly, and I hence transformed (parts of) my answer as a comment for OP to see if he asks something about this. I think the question is non-trivial. The point is that the $a_k$, arising from the transformations, act on a $N$-fold tensor product structure, and not on the "usual" Fock space structure. But perhaps I am missing something?!

Yes that is what I meant! Thank you for summarizing it concisely. It would be nice to know if there is a general correspondence between $a_k|\Omega>$ and $e_k$(and their extension to multiple particle cases).

@TobiasFünke Sorry. Didn't refresh the page. Yea I think I get the explanation using Stone-von Neumann theorem now. Though I don't quite understand the wikipedia page of Stone-von Neumann. But the picture is clear to me now.

Regarding your first comment: this is just the usual Fock space business: $b_k^*|\Omega\rangle=|e_k\rangle$, where the RHS is understood as an element of the one-particle sector of the Fock space, and similarly $b_k^b_q^|\Omega \sim \left(|e_k\rangle \otimes |e_q\rangle + |e_q\rangle \otimes |e_k\rangle \right)$ and so on. Regarding your second: Note that up to now nothing is rigorous, as we for example ignored domain discussions and of course one has to prove that indeed the SvN theorem applies- mathematically, everything is much more complicated than I've written, which I hope is clear.

Yes. It's clear. I have a feeling it can get fairly technical haha. I guess this also induces a structure of graded algebra on the original N particle space? which I find quite interesting.

Yes, I think to really prove it mathematically rigorous is quite hard. But I think intuitively it makes sense (reiterating: the above are just my guesses/intuition, so of course it could be wrong). I also asked myself similar kind of questions, and I think I have an answer myself now (or at least an idea). Regarding graded algebra: This is even further away from what I understand, so I cannot help you with that. --Anyway: If you feel you understood the problem better, consider to write an answer yourself, summarizing your thoughts etc. I don't have time, sorry. Might be useful for others, too.

I mean, in principle, you can, after bringing the Hamiltonian in the QHO-like form, proceed similarly as in the QHO form, argue that there exists a state annihilated by all $a_k$, which is the ground state, and that $H$ admits an ONB of eigenstates constructed by applying powers and products of the $a_k^*$ to this vacuum. Then the isomorphism to the Fock space is even much clearer and evident. I guess the arguments can be made rigorous as well, but might require some work, too.
